C# VSIX project with .NET 8.0
I would like to ask, is it possible to create VSIX project that will use another project as reference (.NET 8.0)?
Because I have created a custom test adapter with .NET 8.0 and I would like to add possibility to update test cases by VS events (OnChange, OnRemove and so on).
But when I create a VSIX project and add reference to assert to my test adapter, I see error:

Test Adapter is not compatible with net48, ... project supports: net80

enter image description here
How to fix if it possible?
Chat GPT said that I can simply create class library and add the vsixmanifest file to create VSIX project for .NET 8.0, but it doesn't work. I didn't find another info about it :(

If the question is essentially "Can you reference .NET 8 from .NET Framework 4.8?" The simple answer is no. No you cannot. If the referenced project can be updated to target .NET Standard 2.0 then that could work.

Test Adapter doesn't work with netstandart2.0

Can you explicitly state what you're trying to do. I initially read your question as if you were trying to reference a .NET 8 project from .NET Framework 4.8. Re-reading your question though it could be the other way around and you want to reference a .NET Framework 4.8 project from .NET 8. Either way, targeting the referenced project to .NET Standard 2.0 would allow either .NET 8 or .NET Framework 4.8 to reference it.

I have a project with tests (custom framework, works only .net8.0), VS doesn't understand these tests as tests.
I decided to create a custom test adapter, I created the class library (.net8.0). Then I have implemented the Discoverer and Executor, did pack as nuget.
This combination works. But it doesn't update TC if I update the .CS file. I found that I have to create an extension for VS, to implement this feature, but I could not, because VSIX project can't work with .net8.0.
With .net standard 2.0 adapter doesn't work, testing project still using .net8.0 and doesn't see my adapter :(

I am afraid not. You can only reference .NET Framework and .NET Standard 2.0 packages from a VSIX  project.
